# mb.BgndGallery Background images in original size -without stretching

Tags: javascript, jquery

BgndGallery" component and try to meke bakground images to be in original size - without stretching. you can watch this here - [mb.BgndGallery](http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-bgndgallery/)

[Here you can better watch this gallery](http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.bgndGallery/demo/demo.html)